# MySQL include all results in ranking

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm using the following query to sort, using `Order by` for 4 different ranks: id, avg_rating, total_sent & points

However, I'm having trouble with including all the members in the results. I'd like to include all members, including the ones that have 0: total_sent, total_received, points, avg_rating, votes

Please help me understand what I'm missing. Thank you.

```
  SELECT m.id, 
         m.Name,
         m.City,
         m.Zip_Code,
         m.url, 
         r.avg_rating, 
         r.votes,
         froms.from_ct total_sent,
         tos.to_ct     total_received,
         froms.from_ct - tos.to_ct `points`
  FROM members m
  JOIN (
    SELECT id_rated, 
           avg(rating) avg_rating,
           count(*) votes
    FROM member_ratings
    GROUP BY id_rated
  ) r ON r.id_rated = m.id
  JOIN ( SELECT id_from, COUNT(*) AS from_ct FROM member_points GROUP BY 1
       ) AS froms  ON froms.id_from = m.id
  JOIN ( SELECT id_received,   COUNT(*) AS   to_ct FROM member_points GROUP BY 1
       ) AS tos    ON tos.id_received = m.id
  WHERE m.Account_Active = 'TRUE'
  GROUP BY m.id, 
           m.Name
  ORDER BY `avg_rating` DESC;
```

Comment: You have a join without condition  (on clause seems missing)...  JOIN member_points mp

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT JOINs for all tables

```
   SELECT m.id, 
         m.Name,
         m.City,
         m.Zip_Code,
         m.url, 
         r.avg_rating, 
         r.votes,
         froms.from_ct total_sent,
         tos.to_ct     total_received,
         froms.from_ct - tos.to_ct `points`
  FROM members m
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_rated, 
           avg(rating) avg_rating,
           count(*) votes
    FROM member_ratings
    GROUP BY id_rated
  ) r ON r.id_rated = m.id
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_from, COUNT(*) AS from_ct FROM member_points GROUP BY 1
       ) AS froms  ON froms.id_from = m.id
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_received,   COUNT(*) AS   to_ct FROM member_points GROUP BY 1
       ) AS tos    ON tos.id_received = m.id
  LEFT JOIN member_points mp ON mp.id_points = m.id
  WHERE m.Account_Active = 'TRUE'
  GROUP BY m.id, 
           m.Name
  ORDER BY `avg_rating` DESC;
```